# websphere datasource connection properties

Tags: oracle, jdbc, websphere

In websphere 8.5, If I have an XA Datasource with a URL as below

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:SID
```

How can I add connection properties related to encoding so that the URL becomes as below:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:SID?useUnicode=no&characterEncoding=ISO-8859-1&characterSetResults=ISO-8859-6
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDBC driver gets user locale and country from JVM, therefore you might try adding the following parameters into JVM arguments (this is an example for locale=Arabic, Country=United Arab Emirates,):

```
-Duser.language=ar -Duser.country=AE
```